# Should I write 'Mechanical Engineering Graduate' or 'Mechanical Engineering graduate'?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, capitalization

*Mechanical Engineering graduate looking for work*... is how my personal statement starts.

Should I capitalize the word *graduate* or leave it as it is?

I have done research using google to see how it is used.

According to this [Biography](https://www.pup.edu.ph/ce/bsme), G is capitalised. Under the year '1986-1991'. quote  *'He was a Mechanical Engineering Graduate of University of..'*.

I have also read a [document](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/159584854.pdf) which uses it in puts everything in lowercase. quote '*mechanical engineering graduate*'.

Also after observing the job listings ' Mechanical Engineering Graduate ' it seemed G was capitalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English nouns are normally kept in ‘sentence case’ unless they are proper nouns. So unless “graduate” is part of the name of the degree, keep it in lowercase.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Can I also ask about the continuation of my personal statements.' ''...use my skills in Mechanics and Mathematics to build ML Algorithms.''  Is that fine?

Comment: @Quad One of the easiest ways to spot a nonnative English speaker is their tendency to capitalize words that aren't capitalized. This doesn't add emphasis or esteem to the concepts; it just makes the sentence look odd. Only the abbreviation "ML" is capitalized here.

Comment: There is no more reason for capital letters for the subject 'mechanical engineering' than there is for degrees in mathematics, computing, biology or history.  It is true that is written in the question, the first word should probably be capitalised.  More sensible, to avoid misunderstanding, would be to write:  "Graduate in mechanical engineering looking for work."  Similarly, there is no reason for capital first letters for mechanics, mathematics or algorithms.

Comment: @Chemomechanics so it should be '...were I can use my skills in mechanics and mathematics to build ML algorithms.  Also suppose I was writing an article let's ' An ML algorithm that does this..' would that be a correct title?

Comment: @Quad This capitalization looks fine. There are no proper nouns in these examples.

Comment: @Chemomechanics thank you for the corrections. On a final note, what if I want to describe a word that is not necessary there but exists. For example, I created a 'Wave Processing Machine Learning algorithm'. Is that fine? another example would be in listing examples that mostly have proper nouns. For instance, - I experimented with Independent Component Analysis(ICA),.. ,... and wave propagations (debating between this and wave propagating equations).

Comment: @Quad None of these are proper nouns.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I have done a bit of research. Would this be the correction?  1)I created a Wave processing machine learning algorithm. 2) - I experimented.... Independent component analysis (ICA), .., .. , wave propagations(PDEs)?

Comment: @Chemomechanics and this, ' I worked in the museum ...'